# When will xslt 2.0 be finished

Tags: browser, xslt-2.0

I really want to start developing in xslt 2.0 but I have been hearing that xslt 2.0 is not supported in browsers yet. Is there an expected date that xslt 2.0 will be done and when will it be supported in browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 is already finished:

[W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/)

But it seems like support is rather lacking.

Wikipedia says:

> XSLT is developed by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). The most recent version is XSLT 2.0[4], which reached W3C recommendation status on 23 January 2007. As of 2010, however, XSLT 1.0[5] is still widely used, as there are no products that support XSLT 2.0 running in the browser, nor on some important server environments such as LAMP.

Comment: Indeed. I imagine this may be a fairly low priority, simply based on the comparatively few people who have used the existing in-browser XSLT 1 support. @Luke101 -- do you really need to use the browser-based XSLT engines? Or could you do your transforms server-side in XSLT 2.0 and throw the results at the browser? Much as client-side XSLT would be great to use sometimes, people are mostly doing XSLT server-side in reality.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT and XPath 2.0 are more than three years old by now, so "they are done". There are various implementations. As for support in browsers, that is lacking and I have not heard that any of the major browser implementers are planning to support it. So doing XSLT 2.0 is certainly possible, client-side XSLT 2.0 is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Kay from Saxonica is working on a client-side implementation of XSLT 2, implemented in Java and translated to Javascript with GWT. Keep an eye on http://saxonica.com

The same will happen with XQuery, over at: http://mxquery.org/